# JS + JS = broken code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I add 2 different javascript codes to the same document, one of them stops working properly; my viewport is meant to follow once the next question is clicked. at the moment it doesn't, and I have no idea why. I have checked variables names etc, and there are no duplicates.

This has happened in the past, and I lost some functionality, I would really like this explained.

http://codepen.io/erayner/pen/mRrMVd (this is my final code)
http://codepen.io/erayner/pen/VPvLyR (this is what it should be doing)

1st code

```
//when you click on an answer, the next answer appears

$(() => {
    init();
});

function init() {
    numberSections();
    bindAnswerClick();
    showSection(0);
}

function numberSections() {
    $(".section").each((index, elem) => {
        $(elem).data("index", index);
        $(elem).attr("data-index", index);
    });
}

function bindAnswerClick() {
    $(".answer").on("click", (e) => {
        selectAnswer($(e.currentTarget));
    });
}

function selectAnswer($answer) {
    let $section = $answer.closest(".section");
    let nextIndex = parseInt($section.data("index")) + 1;

    $section.find(".answer").removeClass("highlight");
    $answer.addClass("highlight");

    showSection(nextIndex);
}

function showSection(index) {
    $(".section[data-index='" + index + "']").show();
}
```

2nd code

```
//variables for end answer

var finalAnswers = [];
var button = document.getElementById("button");
//add answer values together and find end URL for button

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("a[data-value]").on("click", function (e) {
        var value = $(this).attr('data-value');
        finalAnswers.push(value);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $(".Finalbutton").click(function () {
        var store = finalAnswers;
        var frequency = {}; // array of frequency.
        var max = 0; // holds the max frequency.
        var result; // holds the max frequency element.
        for (var v in store) {
            frequency[store[v]] = (frequency[store[v]] || 0) + 1; // increment  frequency.
            if (frequency[store[v]] > max) { // is this frequency > max so far ?
            max = frequency[store[v]]; // update max.
            result = store[v]; // update result.
            }
        }

    if (result == "A")
        button.setAttribute("href", "http://www.w3schools.com");
    if (result == "B")
        button.setAttribute("href", "http://dailydropcap.com/images/C-9.jpg");
    if (result == "C")
        button.setAttribute("href", "http://www.w3schools.com");
    });

});
```

Comment: Demos are helpful but only if they are intuitive or steps are provided to understand how to isolate problem. Have no idea what we should or shouldn't see in your demo

Comment: alright ill add a couple demos.

Comment: You have a lot of errors on your demo, check your browser's console, and fix those `404 errors` first. See screenshot here: http://prntscr.com/dw5ji4

Comment: I have created another codepen - with functionality. see the link above. Please excuse the html errors - they only appear in codepen. Cheers

Comment: the most telling error is `Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery`

Comment: weird error isn't it? it's there though!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason is the following:

When ".answer" is clicked there is executed this code

```
$(".answer").on("click", (e) => {
    selectAnswer($(e.currentTarget));
});
```

But when "`a[data-value]`" is clicked, then "`.answer`" is clicked too. Because of

```
$(".answer").on("click", (e) => {
    selectAnswer($(e.currentTarget));
});
```

is earlier than

```
$("a[data-value]").on("click", function (e) {
    var value = $(this).attr('data-value');
    finalAnswers.push(value);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

so first code is executed, but second not.

You should not use `.on('click',...` syntax. Much better is `addEventListener`.

Let add one `.addEventListener` on possible huge area when actions should be done after click. Syntax is similar to the following:

```
area.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
    if( e.taget ... ){ action 1 } else if( e.target ... ) { action 2 }and so on.
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks! now I just need some more information on how I can make a variable of a[data-value]?

Comment: It is probably not optimal, but try this: `object.tagName == 'a' && object.hasAttribute("data-value")` I do not know how to use selectors in these conditions, so if you will find better solution, let me know.

Comment: jQuery's `.on()` method uses `.addEventListener()` so the advice not to use it does not make sense at all. Don't confuse `.on('click',...` with `.onClick = function (){...`

Comment: thanks slebetman - do you have any other input towards my answer? :)